# Kerberos and Active Directory - where does the Active Directory Server name get set?

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos

Total Kerberos and Active Directory newb here trying to get a very small sample working.

Found a Java Active Directory JAAS example onLine and here is the code.

```
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class ActiveDirectoryValidator
{
  
  private static final String USERNAME = "FOO";
  private static final String PASSWORD = "BAR";
  
  private ActiveDirectoryValidator()
  {
  }
  
  public boolean validateUser(String userName, String password)
  {
  try
    {
      LoginContext lc = null;
      ADCallbackHandler ch = new ADCallbackHandler();
      ch.setUserId(userName);
      ch.setPassword(password);
      lc = new LoginContext("JaasConfig", ch);
      lc.login();
      return true;
    }
    catch (LoginException le)
    {
      System.err.println("Authentication failed:");
      System.err.println("  " + le.getMessage());
      return false;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
    System.err.println("Authentication failed:");
    System.err.println("  " + e.getMessage());
    return false;
    }
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ActiveDirectoryValidator validateUser = new ActiveDirectoryValidator();
    if (validateUser.validateUser(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    {
      System.out.print("Authentication Successful");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.print("Authentication Failed");
    }
  }

}
```

and

```
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ADCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler
{
  private String ADUserId;
  private char[] ADPassword;

  public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws java.io.IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++)
    {
      if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback)
      {
        NameCallback cb = (NameCallback)callbacks[i];
        cb.setName(ADUserId);
      }
      else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback)
      {
        PasswordCallback cb = (PasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
        cb.setPassword(ADPassword);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  public void setUserId(String userid)
  {
    ADUserId = userid;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password)
  {
    ADPassword = new char[password.length()];
    password.getChars(0, ADPassword.length, ADPassword, 0);
  }

}
```

Where does the Active Directory Server name go?

I would not expect it to be in the jaas.conf file as I have seen other programs set it via the UI interface and the jaas.conf file never changes.

What am I missing?

Is this example showing something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved my test to a Linux machine and ultimately found 2 missing components.

1 - when executing, I needed to include the

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=mylocation/jaas.conf
```

2 - I needed to edit the following file to include my Active Directory information

```
 /etc/krb5.conf
```

After making the necessary references and entries, it worked.

Comment: And what Java program did you use that this code was used for in?

Comment: It was extracted out of an application so that it could be tested more easily in a stand-alone program and also to ensure no other code was affecting it.